# Android send SMS from tablet using SMS intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, sms, tablet

I would like to know if it is possible to send a SMS from an Android tablet using the SMS intent? If this is not possible, what are my options?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I would like to know if it is possible to send a SMS from an Android tablet using the SMS intent?

There isn't really an "SMS" `Intent`. There are `ACTION_SEND` and `ACTION_SENDTO` `Intent` actions that could result in an SMS being sent.

With respect to "tablets", most devices with above-average screen sizes do not have telephony capability, and therefore cannot do anything with SMSes, let alone send them in response to `startActivity()` on some `Intent`.

> what are my options?

If you absolutely have to be able to send SMS messages, add `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony"/>` to your manifest, so your app will only be installed on devices that have telephony capability.

If you would like to send SMS messages if that is possible, but work around it if it is not possible, you will want to do three things:

1. Add `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"/>` to your manifest
2. Use `PackageManager` and `hasSystemFeature()` to see if you actually have telephony capability at runtime
3. For devices that have telephony capability, before you call `startActivity()` on your "SMS `Intent`", use `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()` to see if there is anything on the device that will respond to that `Intent`, or wrap your `startActivity()` call in an exception handler to catch the
   `ActivityNotFoundException`

Answer (score 0):

```
String smsNumber = "your number here";
String smsText = "Your text";

Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + smsNumber);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
intent.putExtra("sms_body", smsText);  
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: After "...Uri.parse" I see many examples of "smsto:" and I also see many examples of "sms:"  What is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("sms:"
                        + phoneNumber)));
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

How to check if a tablet has sms service available:

Here the third solution which [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) described in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14259411/1306012) as a method:

```
public static boolean hasSmsService(Context context)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("smsto:123456789"));
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> res = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    if(res.size() > 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is wok for you. try it.........

```
Method :
CAll on button click event.....
sendSMS("Any text",number,sms_string);
```

Now, declare this one out of oncreate();

```
public static void sendSMS(String status, String phoneNumber, String message) {

    Log.e("", "Page : " + status + ", No : " + phoneNumber
            + ",Message Length: " + message.length() + ", Message : "
            + message);
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
}
```